# Atom editor - set it to codeigniter standard - PSR12

Tags: php, atom-editor, psr-12

I'm thinking about changing from sublime text 3 to atom and i want to set the identation standard for codeigniter 4, PSR12.

I've installed globaly via composer the following packages:

1. PHP_CodeSniffer
2. Codeigniter4-Standard
3. PHP-CS-Fixer

Using the following commands:

```
composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"
composer global require codeigniter4/codeigniter4-standard
composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
```

And in the end this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

I've also noticed that my executables are not on the /home/user/.config/composer folder but on the /home/user/.composer folder.

Maybe i did something wrong on this...

On atom, I've installed atom-beautify and php-cs-fixer.

On the atom-beautify my confis are these ones:
General settings:

1. Beautify entire file on save: checked
2. Show loading view: checked

Executables:

**PHP-cs-Fixer -> binary/script path :**

```
/home/{user}/.composer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer
```

**PHPCBF -> Binary/script path:**

```
/home/{user}/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcbf


PHP:
Default Beautifier: PHP-cs-Fixer
Beautify on save: checked
Allow risky rules: no
PHP-CS-Fixer Version: 2
Rules: @PSR12
PHPCBF Standard:
/home/{user}/.composer/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4-standard/CodeIgniter4
```

And finally my atom-beaufity **config.cson**:

```
    "*":
  "atom-beautify":
    executables:
      php: {}
      "php-cs-fixer":
        path: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer"
      phpcbf:
        path: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcbf"
    general:
      _analyticsUserId: "{private-data}"
    php:
      beautify_on_save: true
      rules: "@PSR12"
      standard: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/codeigniter4/codeigniter4-standard/CodeIgniter4"
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    showIndentGuide: true
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "{private-data}"
  "php-cs-fixer":
    executablePath: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer"
    phpExecutablePath: "/usr/bin/php"
```

BTW: Also i would like to ask which plugins do you guys use for web development with php.

Many thanks!

EDIT:

I've managed to set the PSR12 and i will post my new config.cson bellow:

```
    "*":
  "atom-beautify":
    executables:
      php: {}
      "php-cs-fixer":
        path: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer"
      phpcbf:
        path: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcbf"
    general:
      _analyticsUserId: "31b3a718-ab3d-4ec3-96e3-6f5d1c2e2c6b"
    php:
      beautify_on_save: true
      standard: "PSR12"
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    fontSize: 13
    showIndentGuide: true
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "6ecc9e46-806b-4e85-9867-e66075d62870"
  "php-cs-fixer":
    executablePath: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer"
    phpExecutablePath: "/usr/bin/php"
```

The problem now is that atom doesn't "beautify" the php code on the views, only on models and controllers, even tought the view file is also .php

Comment: Can you please add to your post what exactly is the problem? I can see what you did but I don't see any problem being described or what has been done to solve said problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the PHPCBF as the default beautifier and use the following configs (you have to change the executable paths to yours):

```
"*":
  "atom-beautify":
    css:
      beautify_on_save: true
      indent_size: 4
    executables:
      php: {}
      "php-cs-fixer":
        path: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer"
      phpcbf:
        path: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcbf"
    general:
      _analyticsUserId: ""
    php:
      beautify_on_save: true
      default_beautifier: "PHPCBF"
      standard: "PSR12"
  core:
    projectHome: "~/Desktop/Projects/"
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    fontSize: 13
    showIndentGuide: true
    showInvisibles: true
    tabLength: 4
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: ""
  "php-cs-fixer":
    executablePath: "/home/emerson/.composer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer"
    phpExecutablePath: "/usr/bin/php"
```